# How to implement the $regex query with the mongoDB $match query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongodb-query

Here is my code

```
const searchStringResult = (payload.match?.searchString);

  const paginate = [
    {
      $facet: {
        metadata: [{ $count: 'total' }],
        data: [
          { $skip: payload.paginate?.skip || 0 },
          { $limit: payload.paginate?.limit || 10 },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {

        searchfields: {$regex:  searchStringResult,$options: "-i"}
      }
    }
  ];
```

when I console log these code it doesn't show any error

but in console

```
[{"$facet":{"metadata":[{"$count":"total"}],"data":[{"$skip":0},{"$limit":10}]}},{"$match":{"searchfields":{"$regex":"a","$options":"-i"}}}]
```

Comment: this is you have assigned stages in a constant variable, where you have called function for aggregation?

Comment: I am going to return that variable and call that into the aggregation query into my service folder as I am working with nestjs. Here I want to implement the regex query with in the match query. In the regex query I want the search string can be done on the basis of the searchfield but don't know how to do these